# use of [release] in objective C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have a doubt regarding memory management in Objective-C.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSNumber *num=[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10];
[num release];
NSLog(@”%i”,num);
}
```

The above code is working fine by printing the value. But as soon as the object has been released it loses its value right? Then how come its working fine?

Comment: What does it print?  A `%i` means "integer value" and you've given an object pointer;`%@` is the appropriate `NSLog()` value to have it try to print the object (otherwise you're just looking at the integer value of the pointer, presumably...).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on.  First you do this:

```
NSNumber *num=[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10];
```

Your `num` variable now contains a pointer to an `NSNumber` object, and (because you used `alloc`) you *own* that object.  Then you do this:

```
[num release];
```

When you sent `release` to the object, you relinquished your ownership of it.  The object might still exist and be unchanged, or it might have been destroyed.  You don't know.  Your `num` variable still contains the same pointer, but the memory it points to might not be a valid object now so you cannot safely send messages to that object.

Then you do this:

```
NSLog(@”%i”,num);
```

In this `NSLog` statement, you are treating `num` as an *integer*, **not** as a pointer, because `%i` formats an integer.  You're just printing the address (memory location) where the `NSNumber` object was (and might still be - you don't know).  So it doesn't matter whether `num` points to a valid object or not; you're just treating `num` as an arbitrary int.  You're not trying to send any messages to the `NSNumber` object.

Answer (score -1):

1. By Calling [release] on object we can decrement retain count of the object.
2. If object is created by calling method which is having copy, new, alloc in it the caller is said to be owner of that object and owner
   should alway release owned object.
3. If you are not owning the object you should not release it.
4. Always call release on object when object is retained which means if one call retain method the corresponding release call should be
   invoked .Retain release should be matched.